# Vulkan create VK_KHR_surface error: VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT

Tags: vulkan

I am learning Vulkan via [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com) tutorial.
I have created window with GLFW and initialized Vulkan instance without errors. But Vulkan fails to create [VKSurfaceKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkSurfaceKHR.html).

```
bool CreateRenderContext(RenderContext* contextOut)
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
  contextOut->window = glfwCreateWindow(contextOut->width, contextOut->height, "Vulkan", NULL, NULL);

  if(!CreateVulkanInstance(contextOut->instance))
  {
    printf("failed creating vulkan instance\n");
  }

  if(!glfwVulkanSupported())
  {
    return false;
  }

  VkResult err = glfwCreateWindowSurface(contextOut->instance, contextOut->window,nullptr, &contextOut->surface);
  if (err != VK_SUCCESS)
  {
    // Window surface creation failed
    printf("failed to create surface");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

`CreateVulkanInstance`() looks like this:

```
bool CreateVulkanInstance(VkInstance  instanceOut)
```

{

```
  VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
  appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
  appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
  appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
  appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
  appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
  appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

  VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
  createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
  createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

  uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
  const char** glfwExtensions = nullptr;
  glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

  createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
  createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;
  createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

  if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instanceOut) != VK_SUCCESS)
  { 
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

GLFW returns the following required extensions:

```
VK_KHR_surface

VK_KHR_xcb_surface
```

But
      VkResult err = glfwCreateWindowSurface(contextOut->instance, contextOut->window,nullptr, &contextOut->surface);

Returns `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT`

Why the surface creation fails?

My system:
**Ubuntu 18.04 64bit, NVIDIA RTX3000, GPU Driver NVIDIA 430**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating instance into a local variable:

```
bool CreateVulkanInstance(VkInstance  instanceOut) {
   vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instanceOut)
}
```

Probably supposed to be `VkInstance&`.

Comment: Or better still, just `return` it.

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, yea. `NULL` is a null-object for `VkInstance`. No need for raw bools.